# To initialize a transient field, what is the most simple solution

Tags: java, serialization

```
class MyClass implements Serializable {
  transient int myTransient;
  //Other variables
}
```

When I restore this class I want to initialize `myTransient` manually, but otherwise I just want to use the default serialization.

How can I inject an `init()` method into the object restore process without re-writing the entire serialization mechanism as it seems like `Externalizable` would have me do?

Comment: I thought of lazy initialization. Two problems here. If you don't use locking, your variable may be initialized several times. If you do lock, it may slow down you app. See double checked locking for lazy initialization: http://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html. axtavt's solution is better.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Implement a `readObject()` method:

```
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
    throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
    in.defaultReadObject();
    myTransient = ...;
}
```

From javadoc:

> Classes that require special handling during the serialization and deserialization process must implement special methods with these exact signatures:
>
> private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in)
>        throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
>
> The readObject method is responsible for reading from the stream and restoring the classes fields. It may call in.defaultReadObject to invoke the default mechanism for restoring the object's non-static and non-transient fields. The defaultReadObject method uses information in the stream to assign the fields of the object saved in the stream with the correspondingly named fields in the current object. This handles the case when the class has evolved to add new fields. The method does not need to concern itself with the state belonging to its superclasses or subclasses. State is saved by writing the individual fields to the ObjectOutputStream using the writeObject method or by using the methods for primitive data types supported by DataOutput.

**See also:**

- [`Serializable` javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

Comment: You can define your own serialization if you need some features not included in the default implementation, but readObject should be good enough for variable initialization.

Comment: Is this answer still valid for newer versions of JDK/JRE ?